# Nginx configuration with AWS Opsworks

Tags: chef-infra, 3scale

I've installed  the [openresty](http://cookbooks.opscode.com/cookbooks/openresty) cookbook, but now I need to install my config files. What is the best way to add my nginx.conf and nginx.lua files using Chef?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to write your vhost files using a template resource generally:

```
template "#{node['openresty']['dir']}/sites-enabled/mysite.conf" do
  source 'mysite.conf.erb'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '644'
  notifies :reload, node['openresty']['service']['resource']
end
```

I'm unfamiliar with how openresty does lua plugin configs but I would guess it is similar. Make your own cookbook for `mysite` that depends on the `openresty` cookbook and then put your templates in that that cookbook. Don't forget to add your new cookbook to the run list too.